# Mostrar/ocultar layout con botón

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Quiero mostrar y ocultar un layout desde el mismo botón, este es el código xml del layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSearchServices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
```

y este el código en kotlin que tengo hasta ahora:

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener{
        layoutSearchServices.isVisible=true
    }
```

El código funciona pero necesito agregar la parte restante para ocultar el layout, ¿Podéis echarme una mano? Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener el estado de la visibilidad de tu layout, en base a esto mostrarlo o esconderlo:

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener{

    if(layoutSearchServices.visibility == View.VISIBLE ){ //es visible?
        layoutSearchServices.visibility = View.INVISIBLE //esconde vista
    }else{
        layoutSearchServices.visibility = View.VISIBLE  //muestra vista
    }
    
}
```

---

[image: Jorgesys show/hide button]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!